# Is it possible to call a stored function via JPA (JAVA)?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa

As far I know, it is impossible to call a **stored procedure** written in `mysql` with `JPA` but what is with common functions (mysql)?

How can I call a stored mysql function with usage of JPA?

Maybe with the `EntityManager` method `createNativeQuery`?

(Try to make an example)

Comment: yes . you can call procedures using `JPA`...

Comment: Perhaps you ought to read up on JPA 2.1. There are many documents on the internet for it and how to call a StoredProcedure

Comment: refer this >> http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/call-stored-procedures-jpa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far I know, it is impossible to call a stored procedure written in mysql with JPA

No. You can call **stored procedures** from JPA. See [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Stored_Procedures) for an example of how to do it.

> How can I call a stored mysql function with usage of JPA?

You can call a **MySQL stored function** from JPA. JPA 2.1 introduces FUNCTION() function to call any pre-defined (such as [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)) or user-defined functions.

Say, for example, you've defined your own MySQL function such as `shouldGetBonus`

```
CREATE FUNCTION shouldGetBonus (INT department_id, INT project_id) 
RETURNS boolean
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE is_eligible boolean;
  SET is_eligible = -- eligible to get bonus
  RETURN is_eligible;
END$$
```

and then specify your function in your JPQL query, for example,

```
String query = "SELECT DISTINCT e FROM Employee e JOIN e.projects p WHERE FUNCTION('shouldGetBonus', e.department.id, p.id)"
TypedQuery<Employee> emps = entityManager.createQuery(query, Employee.class);
emps.getResultList();
```

Comment: I have found a similar solution. I just used "nativeQuery". However, can I do this:         entityManager.find(Employee.class, FUNCTION('LAST_INSERT_ID()')); but that doesnt work ;(

Comment: No you cannot do this. Read the documentation for [EntityManager#find](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-) method. It expects an Object(Java object which has the identifier value) not a JPQL expression. On the other hand you cannot have a JPQL expression like `FUNCTION('LAST_INSERT_ID()')` as it is not valid grammar defined for JPQL.

Comment: If you have some complex logic in `LAST_INSERT_ID` and not just returns the last inserted id, you have to use [Entitymanager#createNativeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) or one of its overloads to call the stored function.